# Who is the “Ahavas Avos”?

Tags: pirke-avot-ethicsof, authorship

I have a Sefer on Pirkei Avos that has a commentary from the Ahavas Avos. I can’t seem to find who wrote this fantastic commentary, however.

Some helpful additions: the top of the Sefer says “Breslov” so perhaps that helps, and the commentary seems to be a letter to his son explaining the Mishnayot.

Comment: When the author uses the word "בני" (my son), he's referring to the reader, in an endearing manner.

Comment: @Mordechai I'm not promoting R' Schick's books and pamphlets, but if you come across any of them, you will immediately see that this is his style of writing, using words of endearment to the reader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [HebrewBooks website](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/60426) lists the author as Rabbi [Eliezer Shlomo Schick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eliezer_Shlomo_Schick).